# Could not open secure TLS connection to the server

Tags: plesk

How i can fix this problem in plesk control panel

**There was an error sending your message: Could not open secure TLS connection to the server.**

see the error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8hRk.png

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the latest version of GNU TLS library is installed.

As workaround change the IMAP configuration in Horde webmail by editing /usr/share/psa-horde/imp/config/backends.php file:

```
'secure' => 'tls'
'port' => 143
```

to

```
'secure' => 'ssl'
'port' => 993
```